# Getting this error after start Ignite server in 2.0.0 version

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I am using Ignite 2.0.0 version in that while starting ignite server and while   creating cache use  FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(XYZLoader.class) and XYZLoader class is serializable still getting below error

```
Failed to execute job due to unexpected runtime exception    [jobId=62c5bce5d51-f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26,     ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=o.a.i.i.v.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorTask, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1500533972142, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6665e41, clsLdrId=24a5bce5d51-f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=o.a.i.i.v.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorTask, sesId=52c5bce5d51-f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26, startTime=1500534089196, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6665e41, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=true, subjId=f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1533277451]], execName=null], jobId=62c5bce5d51-f81fff08-bdab-4c64-b6f3-e81acebdea26]]
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$ClassFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheJdbcType.list(VisorCacheJdbcType.java:68) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfiguration.<init>(VisorCacheConfiguration.java:186) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.config(VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.java:72) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.run(VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.java:61) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.run(VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorJob.java:32) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.VisorJob.execute(VisorJob.java:69) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6621) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1114) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1379) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:640) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:532) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:743) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:500) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.executeAsync0(IgniteComputeImpl.java:487) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.executeAsync(IgniteComputeImpl.java:467) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.compute.VisorGatewayTask$VisorGatewayJob.execute(VisorGatewayTask.java:445) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6621) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1114) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1379) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:640) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:532) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:743) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:500) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:480) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler.handleAsyncUnsafe(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:227) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler.handleAsync(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:163) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.handleRequest(GridRestProcessor.java:266) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.access$100(GridRestProcessor.java:89) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2.body(GridRestProcessor.java:155) 
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

cache config :

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject> CacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject>();
        CacheConfiguration.setName("TEST");
        CacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(true);
        CacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(true);
        CacheConfiguration.setBackups(2);
        CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Table.class);    CacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(XYZLoader.class));
IgniteCache<String, JSONObject> Cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CacheConfiguration);
```

Comment: please share your config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5781

It's already fixed in master and will end up in 2.2.

Comment: In Apache Ignite 2.2 above issue is not solved. Still getting this error

Comment: It will be available in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your XYZLoader.class extends CacheStoreAdapter

Check this example: [CacheSpringStoreExample](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/spring/CacheSpringStoreExample.java)

Comment: Yes, I have extends CacheStoreAdapter but still getting this exception even though I removed XYZLoader.class then also same exception is throwing. this is happen in ignite 2.0.0 version only

Comment: Do you have started visor?

Comment: Yes I am using GridGain console

Comment: Thank you, This error is produce due to new version of ignite-web-agent-2.1.2 ,

Comment: Or you can use ignite-web-console-2.0.0: https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/v2.0/docs/ignite-web-console

Comment: In Apache Ignite 2.2 above issue is not solved. Still getting this error

Comment: 2.2 was an emergency release that was released earlier than planned. This fix was moved to 2.3 version